# Database Options for in Class Projects

Tags: c#, sql

I'm currently trying to implement a database for my in class project.  I'm collaborating with 2 other students and we're trying to use a database in our C# console application.  I use SQL Express and SQL Management studio at my work but this works well for us because we host our own servers.  At school we don't have that luxury.  We're using github to store our source code but I'm struggling to find a nice way to implement the database in such a way that we can all work remotely and collectively at the same time while managing our database connections in such a way that all our local code will compile nicely.  I'm hoping to find someone who has also dealt with this and can provide a nice solution.

Comment: Point your db connections to localhost and run a DB locally. Use some sort of migrations (SSDT?) to build the DB and populate the data whenever you want

Answer (score 1):

Either run your DB locally (point app to localhost) or else point it to your shared DB.